# Creating Spreadsheets and filling them with specific data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The object is to collect gmail data from incoming and outgoing messages, from within all labels, and log it the information to various spreadsheets, respective to the label they belong to.

Essentially - the label will determine which spreadsheet its corresponding gmail data belongs in. I currently have it all setting into a single spreadsheet. This method will soon become unmanageable.

```
  for (var l = 0; l < labels.length; l++) {// ** Runs a for-loop over "labels array". 
      var label = labels[l].getName();//Gets "this" label name.       
      var labelThreads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads(start, end);//Gets threads in "this" label. (*Set Limits Here*) 
      var labelMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(labelThreads);//Gets array with each email from "this" thread. 

    for (var t = 0; t <labelThreads.length; t++){// ** Runs a for-loop over threads in a label. 
      if (labelMessages[t] == undefined){}// If it's empty, skip.
        else {// If it's not empty.
          emailBody.push([" "]);    
          emailFrom.push([labelMessages[t][0].getFrom()]);
          emailTo.push([labelMessages[t][0].getTo()]);
          emailDate.push([Utilities.formatDate(labelMessages[t][0].getDate(), "GMT", "MMM d, EEE, yyyy - HH:mm")]);
          emailSubject.push([labelMessages[t][0].getSubject()]);
          emailLabel.push([labels[l].getName()]);  
        }
}

  // ** THEN, LOG THE FILLED DATA ARRAYS TO ROWS **
  //getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
    mySheet.getRange(2,2,emailLabel.length,1).setValues(emailLabel);
    mySheet.getRange(2,4,emailFrom.length,1).setValues(emailFrom);
    mySheet.getRange(2,3,emailTo.length,1).setValues(emailTo);
    mySheet.getRange(2,1,emailDate.length,1).setValues(emailDate);
    mySheet.getRange(2,5,emailSubject.length,1).setValues(emailSubject);
    mySheet.getRange(2,6,emailBody.length,1).setValues(emailBody);
  }
}
```

While I was able to programatically create spreadsheets with the same names as all my labels, I don't quite know how to select and fill them with the correct email data.

I understand that my code currently works because the same number of email data is captured in each array, so all the rows of data "line-up" (this information is provided at (start,end).

full code here: http://pastie.org/9768890

**Update- Clarified Question:** The specific question is- how can I separate the information stored in the arrays- emailFrom, emailTo, emailDate, emailSubject, emailLabel, into separate sheets - *by label*. A spreadsheet will have a certain email label name as a title, and I want all email pertaining to that label to be entered into that spreadsheet.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code, or does it work and you just don't understand why?

Comment: my code does not partition and set data into appropriate spreadsheets. it currently only collects data and sets it all in 1 spreadsheet. so there is a problem with the code, nor do i quite understand how to do it. -- I have provided an clearified question in my op

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to open a specific spreadsheet document (not necessarily the active document):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
```

where "id" is a string representing the document ID. If the URL to your spreadsheet is "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc123/edit#gid=0" then the ID is "abc123".

From there, you can access individual sheets like this:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("name");
```

where "name" is a string representing the sheet name.

Once you have your `sheet` variable (or whatever you want to name it), you can insert data just like you already did: use [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) to get the range where you want the data, and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to actually insert the data.

Comment: ok, this is helpful.
the other issue is a tactical one. how do i determine if data across different arrays matches the same email? all emails across various arrays are located on the same index number across all arrays, i think i need to track which labels are on which indices, and then move data across all arrays within those indices to the appropriate sheet.

Comment: Right. If I'm following your code correctly, since you only push data to the various arrays as a group, the indices should all be synced; so emailBody[1] should contain information from the same email as emailFrom[1], and emailTo[1], etc.